# unknown numeric string in picture files name

Tags: android, android-file, android-camera-intent

I am creating jpg images with the camera intent but I can't name them as I would like.
I'm using the following code:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp+ "_";
        File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, 
            JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX,
            getAlbumDir()
        );
        return image;
    }

private File getAlbumDir() {
        File storageDir = null;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
              storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getString(R.string.album_name));
              if (storageDir != null) {
                    if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                          if (! storageDir.exists()){
//                                Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory CameraSample");
                                return null;
                          }
                    }
              }    
        } else {
            // Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name),
            //"External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
        }

        return storageDir;
    } // end getAlbumDir()
```

Each picture name contains JPEG_FILE_PREFIX, timestamp, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX but there is another numeric string between "|" and the JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX: 1238385200. So a file name is like: prefix_20131106_102238_1238385200.JPG

Can I delete that numeric string and how?
Thanks to all

Comment: try to replace | with some other character

Comment: Well, I'm using the "_" I wrote "|" because it was better to see here.

Comment: I fixed it in the post.

Comment: try "-" or "+" as android forbids using "|" in file name

Comment: I mean that my app is using "_" not "|"

Comment: However I tested also without "_" and the result is the same

Comment: 11-06 11:06:45.292: D/MediaScannerReceiver(24155): action: android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE path: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/testing_album/id_20131106_110645_-310233701.JPG